# Allure report shows the past reports as well

Tags: selenium, allure

I am using a simple selenium program on google search. I want to generate an allure report for this.
When i run the same code second or third time, the old reports are also seen.
Whenever I generate an allure report, I want the old reports to be removed and i want only the tests that are run just now.
Is there ant configurations to be done for this.
Please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allure Creates xml in target/allure-result. Before running the code, Include  deletion of  target folder in your code. In that way you will have only one report in the end
I was using ANT so I used :

```
<property name="target.dir" value="${base.dir}/target" />
```

For Deleting

```
<delete dir="${target.dir}" />
```